# Error: Failed finding Lua library. You may need to configure LUA_LIBDIR

Tags: ubuntu, lua, luarocks

I am running ubuntu and installed luarocks,
however, whenever I try to install a something like luasocket (luarocks install luasocket), it throws me the following error:

> Error: Failed finding Lua library. You may need to configure LUA_LIBDIR

Both my config files look like this:

```
    rocks_trees = {
   { name = "user", root = home .. "/.luarocks" };
   { name = "system", root = "/usr/local" };
}
lua_interpreter = "lua5.3";
variables = {
   LUA_DIR = "/usr/include/lua53";
   LUA_BINDIR = "/usr/bin/lua53";
```

}

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the responses, however i got it working by:

uninstalling lua
uninstalling luarocks

installing lua5.1 as well as the development version
installing luarocks as instructed on luarocks.org

the problem for me was i somehow got lua5.3 as my main lua version, but somehow had other version source files, so i just had to completely delete everything and make sure i download consistent versions. 
Hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue in `Ubuntu 22.04`, `lua 5.3`, `luarocks 3.8`, `arm64`. In my system the `/usr/local/opt` directory doesn't exist, so the top answer here didn't help.

In my case, the `LUA_INCDIR` needed to point at `/usr/include/lua5.3`, but the default lua installation (`apt install lua5.3`) doesn't create the necessary file and directories.

Installing `liblua5.3-dev` solved the problem. It creates the needed file and directories in the correct locations.

```bash
apt install liblua5.3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks! This was hardly obvious, but as soon as a `-dev` Lua installation is added with `apt`, it automagically updates `LUA_INCDIR`!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `LUA_LIBDIR` to the variable it should look something like this:

```
rocks_trees = { "/usr/local/lib/luarocks/5.1" }
variables = {
   LUA = "/usr/local/opt/lua/bin/lua5.1",
   LUA_BINDIR = "/usr/local/opt/lua/bin",
   LUA_INCDIR = "/usr/local/opt/lua/include",
   LUA_LIBDIR = "/usr/local/opt/lua/lib",
}
```

Resources for config file:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaRocksConfig

https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Config-file-format

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out!, I tried to do a very similair format, but i could not find the lua folder in opt, even though i have lua installed. Now, i have the error: "fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in Ubuntu 22.04 arm64. The solution for me was to go /usr/bin and remove lua then rename lua5.4 to lua.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, you can use alternatives instead. `/usr/bin/lua` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/lua-interpreter` which in turn points to the correct interpreter for the current Lua version you wish to use as default (e.g. `/usr/bin/lua5.4` if you wish). See the manual page for `update-alternatives` and run `update-alternatives --query lua-interpreter´ to see what alternatives are available for the Lua interpreter.